# How to automatically resize an image to fit the cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Windows 10
Google Sheets

I have a sheet that automatically puts an image in a cell based on the hyperlink I put in the parent cell. [image]

Basically, the cells E14, G14, I14, and K14 are all using the formula `=iferror(arrayformula(image(number)),"")` number is equal to the cell with a link, so **G7, H7, I7, J7**.

This is all fine and dandy, but the problem I've come across is that the images will be too small, too wide, too tall, or too big.

What I'm wondering, is if there's a way to automatically resize the image when it gets put into the cell.

If you look at this image below, you can see the white edges of the images, showing that they don't fit the column width and row height.

[image]

It should look something **Like** this.

[image]

Is there a way to do this? I'm willing to set up a script if I have to. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: In your situation, the images are in the cells. I understood like this. If my understanding is correct, from your figures, are the cells merged? If it's so, I think that it is required to consider it for resizing the cells. When the image size in the cell is changed, it is required to change the cell size. This has already been mentioned by [Rubén's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64850365). So if your cells are merged, I cannot understand that which cells should be changed in the size. And also, in that case, the columns of upper rows of image cells are affected. How about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `IMAGE(url,2)`

---

From https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333?hl=en

> mode - [ OPTIONAL - 1 by default ] - The sizing mode for the image
>
> 1 resizes the image to fit inside the cell, maintaining aspect ratio.
>
> 2 stretches or compresses the image to fit inside the cell, ignoring aspect ratio.
>
> 3 leaves the image at original size, which may cause cropping.
>
> 4 allows the specification of a custom size.

Note that no mode causes the cell to be resized to fit the image.

Comment: What if it's a pasted or inserted image and not a URL?

Comment: @PeterLewis Please post a new question in the proper site.